# XNA Reach profile

Tags: xna-4.0

I get his error

"XNA Framework Reach profile requires TextureAddressMode to be Clamp when using texture sizes that are not powers of two"

for line

```
GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>
                    (PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, verts, 0, 2);
```

What should I do ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

When using a reach profile, use power of two sized textures or set the TextureAddressingMode to Clamp.

The TextureAddressingMode is part of the GraphicsDevice SamplerState.  You need to set this state before your draw call.  The following code shows how to set the first texture sampler to one of the built in sampler states.

```
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;

GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>
                    (PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, verts, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Didn't cut it for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I my case, the Model.fx file was setting the AddressMode to Wrap and that was messing it up.

Here's the correct sampler_state from my Model.fx:

```
sampler TextureSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = (Texture);

    MinFilter = Linear;
    MagFilter = Linear;
    MipFilter = Linear;

    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};
```

More info can be found here: http://www.packtpub.com/article/xna-hsl